# jQuery noUISlider plugin: set events after initialisation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I'm working with the excellent jQuery slider plugin [noUISlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/).

I am able to initialise the slider and set events as follows:

```
var onSlide = function() { console.log('slide'); };
$('#bnv-expert-current').noUiSlider({
      range: [0,100], 
      start: [0,100], 
      step: 10,
      margin: 10,
      slide: onSlide
});
```

However, I would like to initialise the slider first, and then set an event later in the code. Is this possible?

I've tried doing this, to see if it's possible to add an event later:

```
$('#bnv-expert-current').noUiSlider({
      range: [0,100], 
      start: [0,100], 
      step: 10,
      margin: 10
});
$('#bnv-expert-current').noUiSlider({
      margin: 10
});
```

But I get an error.

Comment: For anyone else who lands here, the initial code example doesn't work with recent versions. Use $('element').noUiSlider({range: [0,100]}).on({slide: onSlide}) (https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/issues/166#issuecomment-37759674)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the `change` event at a later time.

```
$('#bnv-expert-current').on('change', function(){
    alert('change');
});
```

Should work for you.

For the `slide` and `set` events I am only aware of one way to initialize them and that is during the initial slider load. ( I can't think of a case where this wouldn't be sufficient though)

```
$('.slider').noUiSlider({
   range: [ 10, 50 ]
   ,start: [ 2, 40 ]
   ,slide: function () {

    /* ... */

   }
   ,set: function () {

    /* ... */

   }
});
```

Comment: @Richard please give feedback on whether this answered your question or not.